# How to create and attach a ELB properly in Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elb, aws-elb

I'm new to Amazon's `Boto3` API. I created a basic diagram of my sample architecture shown below, with an ELB, 4 instances, 2 subnets and and 2 target groups in 2 different Availability Zones (2 instances in each target group).

[image]

I know how to create an EC2 instance, a target group, subnets, and an ELB. But what ELB functions to use, is not clear to me.

How I can attach the ELB to other components? Basically, how to add instances to the ELB? I'm not sure what next steps and functions are needed now.

Here is my simple code so far:

```
def create_load_balancer(load_balancer_name, vpcid, subnets, security_group):
    command = "aws elbv2 create-load-balancer --name " + load_balancer_name + " --subnets " + subnets + " --security-groups " + security_group+" --scheme internet-facing --type application"
    response = os.popen(command).read()

// ....created 4 instances, subnets, and security groups ...

//now ELB:
#Load Balancer
elb = boto3.client('elbv2')
elb.create_target_group( Name='boto3-target-a', Protocol='HTTP',  Port=80, VpcId=vpc.id)
elb.create_target_group( Name='boto3-target-b', Protocol='HTTP',  Port=80, VpcId=vpc.id)
response = elb.create_load_balancer(Name="elb_boto3", Listeners=[ { 'Protocol': 'tcp', 'LoadBalancerPort': 80, 'InstanceProtocol': 'tcp', 'InstancePort': 80, 'SSLCertificateId': 'string'}, ], Subnets=[subnet1,subnet2], SecurityGroups=[sec_group], Scheme='internet-facing', Type='application')
```

Comment: It is normally easiest to implement such a solution using the Management Console first to learn the relationship between components (ELB, Target Group, Listener, Instance, etc). Then, try to implement the same thing using boto3.

Comment: I did the same! But couldn't still figure out the arguments and Arn?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`register_targets()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.register_targets) to attach instances to a Target Group:

```
response = client.register_targets(
    TargetGroupArn='arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:targetgroup/my-targets/73e2d6bc24d8a067',
    Targets=[
        {
            'Id': 'i-80c8dd94',
        },
        {
            'Id': 'i-ceddcd4d',
        },
    ],
)
```

Use [`create_listener()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.create_listener) to associate a Target Group with a Load Balancer:

```
response = client.create_listener(
    DefaultActions=[
        {
            'TargetGroupArn': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:targetgroup/my-targets/73e2d6bc24d8a067',
            'Type': 'forward',
        },
    ],
    LoadBalancerArn='arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:loadbalancer/app/my-load-balancer/50dc6c495c0c9188',
    Port=80,
    Protocol='HTTP',
)
```

From the [`create_target_group()` documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.create_target_group):

> To register targets with the target group, use RegisterTargets . To update the health check settings for the target group, use ModifyTargetGroup . To monitor the health of targets in the target group, use DescribeTargetHealth .
>
> To route traffic to the targets in a target group, specify the target group in an action using CreateListener or CreateRule .

So, the best order of creation is:

- Create Load Balancer
- Create Target Groups
- Create Listeners to link Target Groups to the ELB
- Register instances to Target Groups

Comment: Whs is exactly that Arn? Is it the target group id?! We have to get it or set it?

Comment: `TargetGroupArn` means the unique identifier (Amazon Resource Name) of the Target Group. I have updated my answer with a suggested order of creation.

Comment: Tnx. How should I create listeners for the other target group? inside a single `create_listeners()` or each separately?

Comment: How can I use register_targets with ip addresses?