# Is there a method to add Target Group to LoadBalancer?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I'm trying to launch an application load balancer from java sdk. I noticed that I can add "Target Group" in "Step 4: Configure Routing" through the console but I don't know how to add a target group through code. There seems to be not function like "withTargetGroup".

I just can't find the right documentation which can show me some functions that I can try.

CreateLoadBalancerRequest request = new
                CreateLoadBalancerRequest().withTargetGroup(group_name);

Answer (score 1):

Use [`createListener()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticloadbalancingv2/model/CreateListenerRequest.html).[`withDefaultActions()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticloadbalancingv2/model/CreateListenerRequest.html#withDefaultActions-com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancingv2.model.Action...-)

It looks like you'll need to `setTargetGroupArn` and `setType` as forward.

See a similar answer related to Python: [How to create and attach a ELB properly in Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462600/174777)